# Two sources which have 'callbacks' in the for loop create different results

Tags: javascript

I can not understand why #1 and #2 produce different results.
To my basic understanding 4,4,4,4 is correct, since callbacks exist in the callback queue (you can check this at http://latentflip.com/loupe/).

```
//#1
function func1(a,b,func){
    var k = a + b;
    for (var i =0;i<k;i++){
        func(i);
    }
}

function func2(param){
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(param);
    }, 10);
}

func1(1,3,function(result){
    func2(result);
});
```

result of above #1 >>> 0, 1, 2 ,3

```
//#2
function func1(a,b){
    var k = a + b;
    for (var i =0;i<k;i++){
        setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i);
    }, 10);
    }
}

func1(1,3);
```

result of above #2 >>> 4, 4, 4, 4

Comment: you need to read about closures to understand this.

Comment: @Manish it's not really a closures problem, though I understand how relative novices might think it was

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first function prints the `i` var.

The second one increases `i` while it keeps going in the `for` loop, and when the timeout ends `i=4`, so it prints 4 times 4.

This because it is an async function.

The right way to do what you want to is the first one, calling another function to force the `console.log(i)` and not keep going until the `func2` ends.

Answer (score 1):

In the second example you are calling the wait function within the for loop itself, which causes the JavaScript to execute the queued `console.log` commands only after the value of `i` has finished incrementing.

In the first example, the function with the log statement is called externally, and only returns to the for loop once the output has been printed. The callback correctly prevents further execution of the loop until each call to the external function has been completed.